# Auth guard driver [api] is not defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, jwt

I am using `laravel 5.4` and using `jwt auth`
jwt version is `jwt-auth "tymon/jwt-auth": "0.5.*"`

In auth.php i have

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
```

In Api.php i have

```
 Route::post('/login','HomeController@authenticate');


Route::group(['prefix' => 'v2','middleware' => 'auth:api',], function () {

    // Authentication Routes...
   Route::get('/logout','HomeController@logout');
Route::get('/home','HomeController@home');

});
```

When i post email and password from postman it will return token .

when i try to acccess

http://localhost/demo/public/api/v2/home

and header i passed Authorization bearer token

I am getting following error in postman

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong. (1/1)
>   InvalidArgumentException Auth guard driver [api] is not defined. in
>   AuthManager.php (line 99) at AuthManager->resolve('api') in
>   AuthManager.php (line 70) at AuthManager->guard('api') in
>   Authenticate.php (line 61) at Authenticate->authenticate(array('api'))

can any help me how to fix it

Also i checked follwing issue since its old one  Sep 27, 2016
https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/860

Answer (score 4):

try to set `token`:

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token', // here !
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in your kernel.php file you've declared it in

```html
 protected $routeMiddleware =
```

Comment: this does not solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily an answer, but this is the article I have used a couple times to install and setup JWT tokens and I have had no issues.

https://medium.com/employbl/build-authentication-into-your-laravel-api-with-json-web-tokens-jwt-cd223ace8d1a

Hopefully this helps, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding this line to the providers in config\app.php

```
   'providers' => [
       ...
    Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider::class,
   ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The error may occur if the `API` guard does not exist. In order to solve this issue, you have to set the `API` guard on

```
root->config->auth.php [line:38]
```

as follows

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token', // make sure to add token on API driver
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
```

the request from the default register form will have following inputs

```
local.DEBUG: array (
  '_token' => 'J0FzfW7huNaJxcUZnjYXF9g63OOiSHaH9vZSBc73', // token is required from the request
  'name' => 'mygem',
  'phone' => '+1 (484) 853-6668',
  'email' => 'cyvu@mailinator.com',
  'password' => 'Pa$$w0rd!',
  'password_confirmation' => 'Pa$$w0rd!',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I solved it by adding

```
"tymon/jwt-auth": "^1.0"
```

in the `require array` of `composer.json`, then running `composer install`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RoadRunner than you need to add to `app/config/roadrunner.php` section `'reset_providers'` Laravel Service Prodiver for JWT auth:  `\PHPOpenSourceSaver\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider::class`

see https://github.com/roadrunner-php/laravel-bridge/issues/15